# conditional select between multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

I have a table with a certain flag called FL_virtual, if this flag equals 1 i need to get my stock in a special way using a function

now i want to make a select statement with it but depending on this flag i need to adjust my select to use a certain function instead of a subquery

so presume i start with this select statement

`select product_name,..(other options from the product table), 
(select sum(qy_stock) from STOCK where warehouse_id = 1) as 'qy_stock_internal',
(select sum(qy_stock) from STOCK where warehouse_id = 2) as qy_stock_external 
From product`

now i need to change the subquery (qy_stock) with a call to a function when the fl_virtual flag is 1

so that it becomes like this

`select product_name,..(other options from the product table),
 FN_GET_stock_PRODUCT(1) as qy_stock_internal,
 FN_GET_stock_PRODUCT(2) as qy_stock_external
from product`

so i thought a simple if then else structure will do but for some reason i can't get it to work
this is how i thought it would look

```
select product_name,..(other options from the product table),
 IF fl_virtual > 0 THEN 
(select sum(qy_stock) from STOCK where warehouse_id = 1) as 'qy_stock_internal',
(select sum(qy_stock) from STOCK where warehouse_id = 2) as qy_stock_external

ELSE  

FN_GET_stock_PRODUCT(1) as qy_stock_internal,
FN_GET_stock_PRODUCT(2) as qy_stock_external
END IF
```

but it doesn't work , anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close - just use `CASE` instead of `IF` (you have to repeat your condition, since you cannot easily return two columns from a single CASE (see P.S.):

```
select product_name,
       ..(other options from the product table),
       (CASE
         WHEN fl_virtual > 0 THEN
          (select sum(qy_stock) from STOCK where warehouse_id = 1)
         ELSE
          FN_GET_stock_PRODUCT(1)
       END) as qy_stock_internal,
       (CASE
         WHEN fl_virtual > 0 THEN
          (select sum(qy_stock) from STOCK where warehouse_id = 2)
         ELSE
          FN_GET_stock_PRODUCT(2)
       END) as qy_stock_external
```

P.S.: It *is* possible to return multiple values from a single CASE, e.g. using Object Types, but that's stuff for a different question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a union select with those 2 different queries and contitions.

Btw. the names stock and warehouse look like a typical school work examin.